# Is there any way to redirect the page first then execute the remaining code

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, redirect

I am new to azure web app, Is there any way to redirect the page first then execute the remaining code? I am stuck in situation where I have to redirect my page first, then execute the remaining code... Actually I have deployed my code on azure web app which has request timeout for about 4 mins (which is not configurable), my code take approx 15 min to execute, I want to redirect to main page and execute the remaining code in background. I have tried threads and parallel programming also still no luck.. I am not able to overcome the time frame my web page get request time out every time. Is there a way anyone can suggest?

Thanks for help!

```
/*functionA and functionB are not execute after redirecting.*/
private static async Task <int> functionA(para1, para2)
{ 
   Task<int> temp1 = await functionB(y,z); 
    return int;
 }

 private static async Task<int> functionB(para1, para2)
 {
    return int;
 }
/* This method will execute first  */
 private string functionC(para1, para2, para3)
 {
    console.log("hello world");
    redirect.response("www.xyz.com");
    Task<int> temp = await functionA(x,y);

    return str; //return string type value
 }
```

Comment: please put what you have try or some code.

Comment: have you try async method? or you can create background service for it.

Comment: I will second the async suggestion

Comment: if you are trying to execute as part of a web app but want to redirect first have you considered placing your in its own web job?  you could then put a message on a service bus queue or topic from your webapp and have the message picked and executed independently.

Comment: @Chao226 yes i was seeking out to know whether there is an alternate way to do the same task rather than using azure web job and storage queue thanks for your help

Comment: @ShadabAli  I think webjob would be the best option with the execution time.  azure functions would be an alternative but with the amount of time it takes to execute it may not be cost effective.  can the process be broken down into smaller more efficient functions?  Is the time taken being bloated buy calls to database/api?  if so you could also look at a azure logic app which could handle any data access and the call azure functions to handle the processing

Answer (score 0):

If you've got heavy processing that will result in a HTTP timeout, I suggest looking into offloading processing to a WebJob or Azure Function. It would work as follows:

1. Your Azure WebApp receives a HTTP request for a long-running operation. It gathers the necessary information, creates a Service Bus Queue message, and fires the message off. Your WebApp then responds to the user by telling them that the processing has begun.
2. Provision a separate WebJob or Azure Function that monitors your Service Bus Queue for messages. When a message is received, the WebJob/Function can perform the processing.
3. You will probably want to tell your user when the operation has completed and what the result is. You have a few options. The slickest would be to use SignalR to push notifications that the operation has completed to your users. A less sophisticated would be to have your WebJob/Function update a database record, then have your HTTP clients poll for the result.

I've personally used this pattern with Service Bus Queues/WebJobs/SignalR, and have been very pleased with the results.

Comment: thanks Rob Reagan .. yes there is heavy processing that results to HTTP request timeout, I was just searching for an alternate way to do that ... thanks for your help

Comment: @ShadabAli, did this answer your question?

Comment: yes it does help me to know that it's only way to resolve my issue @RobReagan thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous operations in Azure storage queues and WebJobs can help in situation as stated
i have referred this

> https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/2254